# Melting Sculpture

Tags: integration

I couldn't get the correct answer for this question:

A beautiful ice sculpture is melting, with its volume changing at a rate of:
$$V'(t)=\frac{40}{t^{1/2}(t^{1/2}-10)} ft^3/hr$$
If after 1 hour, the volume of the sculpture is 280 $ft^3$, find its volume after 36 hours. If the sculpture has melted completely, put $0$. Round your answer to 3 decimal places.

What I did was I integrated the equation with the upper bound 36 and lower bound 1, and got $-64.874$. Then, I added the number to 280, and my final answer was 215.126, which was wrong. Can someone correct my mistake?
Thank you.

Comment: @coreyman317 Shouldn't it be the decrease in volume over the period?  You're integrating the derivative.

Comment: @coreyman317 Yes, it would, $$\int_{t_0}^{t_1} V'(t)\mathrm{dt}=V(t_1)-V(t_0)$$

Comment: @coreyman317 No, it makes no physical sense.  If the sculpture is melting, the derivative of the volume is negative, so the integral is negative, and the situation you envision doesn't arise.  If the sculpture were somehow gaining volume, say by being sprayed with ice-cold water, then the derivative would be positive.